# using jsrender with laravel

Tags: laravel, jsrender

Helo, 
I would like to jsrender in combination with laravel but i've experienced some problems with the blade engine, since they both use the double bracket notation to store data a can't get them to compile.

In my blade file i have:

```
@include('templates/note');
```

and then my template in 'templates/note.blade.php'.

But offcourse thats giving me problems with the `{{}}`

So how would it be possible to use jsrender in combination with laravel?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JsRender and JsViews you can set your own choice of delimiters rather than use the default "{{", "}}".

See [Setting tag delimiters for JsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters) for documentation.

And here is a test case that shows it: [$.views.settings.delimiters("@%","%@");](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/test/unit-tests/tests-jsrender-no-jquery.js#L508)

Answer (score 4):

> **[UPDATE]** 
>   Apparently this doesn't work on Laravel >= 5.4 according to this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17736. So you can use `@{{ }}` instead to stop blade from compiling the tag.

You can change the blade engine's content tags / delimiters instead. By using the setContentTags() function. For example, I usually use :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Blade;
use View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');
        Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%!!', '!!%>');

        View::addExtension('jsv.html', 'blade');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I place it in the boot function in AppServiceProvider.php to run it before everything else.